# Remove index from sidemenu user type wise

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have implemented side menu in tableview and now my scenario is like, I have to manage sidemenu options as user types

Let me show my code

```
var items = ["Social Media Post", "Messages", "Manage User","My Account","Information","Logout"]



 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MenuTableViewCell
        cell.lblTitle.text = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.imgMenuLogo.image = image[indexPath.row]
        print(User_type)
        if User_type == 2{
            items.remove(at: 0)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

but now i want . to de like this

```
   if user_type == "3"{
    // Social Media , Messages And Manage User options i want to remove 

}
```

I am not able to understand how to remove from index.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getList()
}

func getList(){
    switch userType{
    case 0:
        items = ["UserTypeOne_Home","UserType_One Settings","etc"]
        break
    case 1:
        items = ["UserTypeTwo_Home","UserType_Two Settings","etc"]
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Some ID")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
}
```

Try not to change the array from within the cellForRowAt indexPath method using indexPath.row, that will not give you the result you want. Modulate the array from outside the protocol method overrides, and just call the reloadData() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use enum of UserType and check type of current user than Make an array with default options available to every user and then append specific data in array according to user type. Hope it clarifies :)

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MenuTableViewCell
    cell.lblTitle.text = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgMenuLogo.image = image[indexPath.row]
    print(User_type)
    if User_type == 2{
        items.remove(at: 0)
    }
    return cell
}
```

This will work, But you have done a small mistake here.

You have removed from array after setting label. So you need to remove the item from array first then do set label.

Btw, I will not recommend this method as you need to add/remove from array for every `cellForRowAt` method.